# java - how to limit sending email by 3rd party tools?

Tags: windows, security, smtp, java, jenkins

I have a (Win2008 R2) box running the Jenkins continuous integration server.

It's a java program running as a Windows service.

The command line looks like this:

```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java.exe" -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war" [more params]
```

I want Jenkins to be able to send email (e.g. when a build fails).

The box runs a McAffee firewall that blocks everything except a whitelist of programs/ports.

I have added a whitelist rule allowing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java.exe` to acccess the SMTP port (25).

The problem is, a 3rd party java program could use the same `java.exe` to execute, and thus would be able to send email.

How do I fix that?

FWIW the Jenkins server runs as a specific user account ("autobuild")

Answer (score 1):

Limit access to a relay server that requires authentication and configure the auth data into your Jenkins instance.